# Make the heart bounce in and out

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I was able to make a heart in matlab as:

```
n=100;
x=linspace(-3,3,n);
y=linspace(-3,3,n);
z=linspace(-3,3,n);
[X,Y,Z]=ndgrid(x,y,z);
F=((-(X.^2) .* (Z.^3) -(9/80).*(Y.^2).*(Z.^3)) + ((X.^2) + (9/4).* (Y.^2) + (Z.^2)-1).^3);
isosurface(F,0)
lighting phong
axis equal
```

Would it be possible to make it bounce in and out? What approach might be taken?

Comment: Take a look at this [implementation](https://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2009/02/13/heart-model-for-valentines-day/) in FileExchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
step = 0.05;
x = -1.5 : step : 1.5;
y =   -1 : step : 1;
z = -1.5 : step : 1.5;

[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(x, y, z);

f = (X.^2 + 9/4 .* Y.^2 + Z.^2 - 1).^3 - X.^2 .* Z.^3 - 9/80 .* Y.^2 .* Z.^3;

isosurface(X,Y,Z,f,0)

axis tight
axis equal
colormap flag
axis manual

ax = gca;

k=1.25;
ax.XLim = ax.XLim*k;
ax.YLim = ax.YLim*k;
ax.ZLim = ax.ZLim*k;

tempLims.XLim = ax.XLim;
tempLims.YLim = ax.YLim;
tempLims.ZLim = ax.ZLim;

t=0;

heartData = sin((1:250)/100*2*pi)/6.*hamming(250)';
heartData(251:400) = 0;

while 1
    t=t+1;
    t=mod(t, length(heartData))+1;

    k = 1 + heartData(t);

    ax.XLim = tempLims.XLim * k;
    ax.YLim = tempLims.YLim * k;
    ax.ZLim = tempLims.XLim * k;
    pause(0.01);
end
```